# How to use item-text and item-value in Vuetify v-combobox?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

## My Problem with Vuetify's v-combobox

### Description

I am having a problem. In the v-combobox the options are labeled `[object Object]` instead of the University's name... I really would like to use the v-combobox as it is both good for autocompleted and custom inputs. I don't trust that the Database that the API accesses is complete and always up to date, thus leaving the users the ability to type in their own University if it's not in the dataset is in my interest. My mental state is slowly degrading...

### Code

```js
<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="universityName"
    :items="universities"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="name"
    hide-details
    label="University Name"
    @update:modelValue="filterUniversities"
    :return-object="false"
  />
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      universityName: '',
      universities: [], // List to store autocomplete suggestions
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterUniversities: _.debounce(async function(search) {
      if (!search) return;
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=${encodeURIComponent(search)}`);
        this.universities = response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching universities:', error);
        // Handle the error in the UI, e.g., show a message to the user
      }
    }, 500), // Debounce the input by 500ms
  }
}
</script>
```

### What have I tried

Bombarding ChatGPT and a ChatGPT fine-tuned model with questions.
Applying other redditor's or overflower's solutions of their problems to mine.
Mental Breakdown.
Crying.
Alcoholism.

Comment: The console warnings when you run this code gives a hint that the title prop is invalid. Checking the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-item-title), the prop should be `item-title` not `item-text`.  Also, you have a syntax error on the line `:label="University Name"`. You should not bind a string literal with `:`, just remove it to be `label="University Name"`

Comment: oh yeah the binding is because i really use i18n and have it actually bound and not just as a const string. thx